# Do CMOS batteries drain faster depending on how long and often you use your PC?

Tags: bios, motherboard, power, desktop-computer, power-management

I have recently been thinking about how the lifetime of CMOS batteries is related to the time percentage during which one's PC is up. Obviously, the amount of power consumed by CMOS boards is incredibly low compared to the power that is being pulled from the wall socket by the whole active PC, but is still non-zero. It makes me wonder whether the CMOS batteries are losing more juice because of the power CMOS is draining, or the aging process itself that degrades the batteries' structure and ultimately leads to the button cell's death. For reference, CMOS batteries are of the type commonly named "button cells", and have a nominal voltage of 3 V; they are considered fully depleted once the voltage drops to 2.0 V or less.

CMOS batteries are required to maintain a constant power supply for the real-time clock so that it continues to track the passage of time even after you have plugged the PC off the wall socket. They also power the volatile storage component that is responsible for retaining the BIOS settings. However, once you power the PC on, one could wonder whether or not the CMOS switches from draining the juice from the button cell to obtaining it by getting it from the same source all other PC components do. Without CMOS power, PC will still boot (at least mine will do) and ask you whether or not do you want to go with the default settings, but then it retains those settings until you have turned the PC off; it does not keep asking as long as it stays on. If it does indeed switch, then it could suggest that the button cell gets drained slower if your PC is on, extending its lifetime.

On the other hand, for a person not really intimate with technology, a "common sense" approach might suggest that batteries in PCs could behave similarly to those in flashlights: the more you use a device, the faster the batteries will drain.

If I tend to have my PC always on, will it, on average, drain CMOS batteries faster compared to if I was having the PC on for just a single hour a day? How would the frequency of restarts during usage affect CMOS's power consumption drained from the batteries?

Comment: I have had a desktop computer running non-stop for over two decades and never replaced a CMOS battery.

Comment: For some reason, after I clicked "post question", a notification had been generated that said _"The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed"_. I am wondering whether it was a message from an actual person had been following and reading my post in real time as I was in the process of writing it, or maybe it was some AI looking at the catchphrases. Either way, I welcome all suggestions of improvement, but I am incredibly puzzled as to how my question could be subjective. I would consider it to be quite technical having potential of generating reference-based answers.

Comment: @John That's impressive, that timespan is two times longer than the expected shelf-life of the highest quality button cell batteries. Thank you for response. However, to be specific, by "running non-stop" you mean literally never having had any power outages nor switching the PC off even least once during those two decades, or have you actually had some rare events of such? I am asking because if the former is the case, then your CMOS-powering cell could had been completely discharged long ago without any effects (until you switch off, of course).

Comment: Not sure it rises to the level of an answer since I don't have empirical evidence, but the RTC battery is supposed to be a backup to system power.  So it seems likely that a system that is disconnected from power would consume that battery faster.  It would not surprise me if the standby power of an ATX MB got channeled to the RTC so it might have to be unplugged or power battery removed on a modern system.

Comment: @user1699905 - There are zero close votes on your question.  However, I sort of agree with the notion, that your question is sort of objective.  CMOS batteries have a fixed lifespan, how long they last, is really situational.  While not a CMOS battery, I recently had a software failure caused by an internal error detection in a SAN, the hardware would boot then wait (awhile with a yellow light) until the battery was charged.  The battery in this case was a backup battery, that lasted nearly 15 years, and was only replaced due to the long boot time that required an Administrator to fix

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you for information about that. Could you give me some pointers as to how I can modify my post to be less subjective, if I can do that at all with such a type of question? 15 year lifetime is impressive. Do you remember what cell type that was? For reference, CMOS batteries tend to use 3V cells named CR2032.

Comment: @davolfman That's exactly the conclusion my thinking process led me to as well! Thanks for response. I am really curious whether it could be objectively, technically confirmed or dismissed.

Comment: @user1699905 - It was a backup battery to a Dell SAN, the battery of course, is only used to finish writing to the array in the event of sudden power loss.

Comment: I should note that I had several desktops each lasting 6 years or more (not one machine going over 2 decades) . Sorry to mislead

Comment: I have a machine that has been up and running for close to two decades nonstop (my media center PC). It is an AMD athalon thunderbird piece of c**p running on an asus mobo.  It initially had XP.. then I upgraded to XP media center on it around 2005.. then upgraded it to 7.  I do occasionally shut it down to blow it out with my air compressor.. and the occasional power outage.. otherwise still fine.  I guess I didnt think about the CMOS lifespan.  I guess i am lucky.